# Problems running HTTPS server

Tags: java, http, ssl, https

I wrote the HTTPS server using the example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html).

Server code:

```
public class HTTPSServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 5);
    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());

    char[] storepass = "storepass".toCharArray();
    char[] keypass = "serverpass".toCharArray();

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(HTTPSServer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("web-vision.jks"), storepass);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, keypass);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[]{}, null);

   server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {

       @Override
       public void configure (HttpsParameters params) {

           // get the remote address if needed
           InetSocketAddress remote = params.getClientAddress();

           SSLContext c = getSSLContext();

           // get the default parameters
           SSLParameters sslparams = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();

           params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
           // statement above could throw IAE if any params invalid.
           // eg. if app has a UI and parameters supplied by a user.

       }
   });

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    server.setExecutor(executor); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
    executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

      String response = "This is the response";
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
      OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
      os.write(response.getBytes());
    }
}
```

For this server, I've created a file with keys with the command:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore web-vision.jks -dname "CN=localhost, OU=gg, O=NA, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=RU" -storepass storepass -alias server-test -keypass serverpass
```

Next, I put this file in the project resources.

Then I start this server and try to connect to it and to get an answer by visiting `https://10.155.26.68:8080/` and `https://localhost:8080/`, but there is no answer, the server is unavailable.

Prior to this, I implemented the simplest HTTP server and it worked fine.

Connecting to the HTTPS server with curl yields this error:

> curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 10.155.26.68:8080

[image: screenshot of calling curl]

**Update:**

Thanks for the help, but the problem was solved only by creating a new certificate using the command:

```
keytool -v -genkey -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Developers, O=NA, L=Ufa, C=RB" -alias parent -storetype jks -keystore vision.jks -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass mystorepass -keypass mykeypass
```

I'm just learning SSL and maybe the first certificate was created incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace or error message?

Comment: There are no errors when starting and running the server, but the server does not respond in the browser

Comment: *"... but there is no answer, the server is unavailable."*  - We need a more precise answer than that.  Try connecting to the server using `curl` (or equivalent) and tell us exactly what happens.

Comment: curl gives this error `C:\curl-7.65.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl https://10.155.26.68:8080/`
`curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 10.155.26.68:8080`

Comment: @A1exNS Can you edit your answer and add the output of `curl -vv https://10.155.26.68:8080/` ?

Comment: Which Java? Works as expected for me with (Windows) 7u80,8u212,11.0.2 against `openssl s_client` (I don't have latest curl). Try running with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` and get the last 50-100 lines or so of debug output (you may need to use a larger console or redirect to a file). PS: conventionally 8080 is http and 8443 is https, but 8080 https should technically work, it just tends to confuse people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable reason you encountered `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` with curl, is that when creating your certificate with `keytool`, you didn't specify the algorithm to use.

In this case, `keytool` defaults to using [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm).

Then, during the handshake phase with curl, the server can't find a common authentication scheme and throws an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:945)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:934)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1224)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1160)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:849)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:810)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1052)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:999)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams.doHandshake(SSLStreams.java:464)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams.recvData(SSLStreams.java:418)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams$InputStream.read(SSLStreams.java:522)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams$InputStream.read(SSLStreams.java:591)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.Request.readLine(Request.java:80)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.Request.<init>(Request.java:50)
        at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Since this exception is logged at log level `FINER` by `sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run` it's difficult to detect.

As you figured out, calling `keytool` with `-keyalg RSA` to generate the certificate, makes server and client find an authentication scheme which fixes that issue:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass secret_password -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Developers, O=NA, L=Ufa, C=RB"
```